# Remove the specific user group to execute all stored procedures on the specific database

Tags: sql-server, sql-grant, sql-revoke

I would like to have one script to remove the specific user group to execute all stored procedures on the specific database in SQL Server 2014. I searched the web and found the example at [Grant Revoke Permissions On Stored Procedures in SQL Server](https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2012/05/29/grant-revoke-permissions-on-stored-procedures-in-sql-server). It looks like I need create the script for all stored procedure.

Also I found another website [REVOKE Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-object-permissions-transact-sql). However I have no clue how to write it as one script for all stored procedure.

Also I tried to use the below script in the database, but the Sales group still has permission on the stored procedure.

```
revoke execute to [Sales]
```

Would anyone tell me what should I do?